# Cannot find field in T:tuple

Tags: apache-pig

My data is:

```
(10,1) [70#3300]
(10,2) [71#3300]
(10,1) [70#3300]
(11,1) [71#3300]
(12,1) [72#3300]
(10,3) [74#3300]
```

and the rest are:

```
grunt> a = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/complex_2.txt'  USING PigStorage(' ') AS (T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int),M:[mileslogged:int]);
grunt> medians = FOREACH (GROUP a ALL) GENERATE a.T;
```

The output of the below command

```
grunt> describe medians;
```

is

```
medians: {{(T: (driverId: int,week: int))}}
```

but when I run

```
    m1 = FOREACH medians GENERATE T.driverId;
```

I get the below error:

```
2020-07-24 00:24:32,094 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1128: Cannot find field driverId in T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int)
  Details at logfile: /home/maria_dev/pig_1595549443230.log
```

How can I only select driverId(s)?

Comment: I think the extra set of {} around the statement means that the tuple is in a bag. Try to FLATTEN the bag first and then index the field: 

m1 = FOREACH medians GENERATE FLATTEN(T).driverId;

Comment: grunt> m1 = FOREACH medians GENERATE FLATTEN(T).driverId;
2020-07-24 00:48:55,439 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 3, column 40>  mismatched input '.' expecting SEMI_COLON
Details at logfile: /home/maria_dev/pig_1595551585633.log

Comment: grunt> m1 = FOREACH medians GENERATE FLATTEN(T);
2020-07-24 00:50:15,656 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:
<line 3, column 38> Invalid field projection. Projected field [T] does not exist in schema: :bag{:tuple(T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int))}.
Details at logfile: /home/maria_dev/pig_1595551585633.log

Comment: So for the first reply the semi colon was missing. For the second reply you have flattened T, but not assigned it to any name. So when you call T again, it can't be found. FLATTEN(T) AS T; Or you should still be able to FLATTEN(T).driverId AS driverId;

Comment: still does not work,  m1 = FOREACH medians GENERATE FLATTEN(T) as T;
2020-07-24 00:58:20,316 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:
<line 3, column 38> Invalid field projection. Projected field [T] does not exist in schema: :bag{:tuple(T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int))}.
Details at logfile: /home/maria_dev/pig_1595552092465.log

Comment: m1 = FOREACH medians GENERATE FLATTEN(T).driverId as did;
2020-07-24 00:58:01,675 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 3, column 40>  mismatched input '.' expecting SEMI_COLON
Details at logfile: /home/maria_dev/pig_1595552092465.log

Comment: If I put the source, maybe it would be easier and it can be replicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/complex_2.txt'  USING PigStorage(' ') AS (T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int),M:[mileslogged:int]);

medians = FOREACH (GROUP a ALL) GENERATE FLATTEN(a.T) AS T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int);

driverIds = FOREACH medians GENERATE T.driverId;
```

Comment: Thanks, excellent, can you please elaborate what was the reason that you have added the AS T:tuple(driverId:int,week:int) to the FOREACH group, how did you find out that that it needs a schema

Comment: So you don't need the schema, you could reference FOREACH medians GENERATE T.$0 to get the first element of the tuple. I assumed in the comments above this would work at the same time as flattening, but looks like you need to flatten first, then index.